# Install CKeditor using Bower

Tags: ckeditor, package-managers, bower

I am struggling to install ckeditor with Bower, I have tried a bunch of different things but each time I end up with just a `.bower.json` file and a `Readme` file or `index` file. I never get more than 2 files :( I am able to install other packages just fine, so I know things are set up ok.

Here are some things I have tried:

```
    {
       "dependencies": {
          "ckeditor": "latest",

          "ckeditor": "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/releases/tag/4.2.1/standard",

          "ckeditor": "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/releases/tag/4.2.1/standard",

          "ckeditor": "https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/commit/a822d585d4ebf8d969fa" 
       }
    }
```

Why is this package different than the rest? What is the key to crack it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since version **4.3.3** CKEditor introduced support for Bower. You may simply install it with following command:

```
bower install ckeditor
```

You may also download it by setting dependencies in your `bower.json`:

```
{
    "name": "my-project",
    "dependencies": {
        "ckeditor": "4"
    }
}
```

After that fetch dependencies with:

```
bower update
```

Note: that it will download **standard-all** preset, which essentially contains all the official plugins available, but only part of them enabled in configuration.

More information can be found in [CKEditor package managers guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_package_managers).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you want a specific preset with a specific version of ckeditor.

First off, here is a helpful [ckeditor post](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-Supports-Bower-and-Composer) that will facilitate the required syntax to specify the repository tag.

Here is an example of what to include in your bower.json file:

```
{
 name: "your-name",
  "dependencies": {
      "ckeditor": "#full/4.3.3"
  }
}
```

Simply swap out 'full' with either basic, standard, or which ever you desire as well as the version.

then run:

```
bower update
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have any valid [semver](http://semver.org/) git tagged releases so Bower tries to fetch the [`master`](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-releases/tree/master) branch, which only contains the readme. Use `bower install ckeditor#stable/standard` instead.

Comment: cool, this works. Looks like this if using bower.json "ckeditor": "#stable/standard". Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know - we'll be switching to semver tags soon.

Comment: For the basic editor replace `standard` with `basic` so it would be in bower.json: `"ckeditor": "#stable/basic",`

Comment: To help others who are googling for the full version: using `"bower install ckeditor#stable/full"` from commandline or `"ckeditor": "#stable/full"` from bower.json will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Now it will work if you just use:

```
'ckeditor: "*"'
```

inside your bower.json. this will, however only pull the standard version. For more information on this issue see:

[dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11279](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11279)